# Preprocessing data distinguishing extremely clustered numerical from discrete/categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization, clumping

I have a data set of approximately 70 features and I would like to train a classification model on them.

The features are characters on one hand that I would definitely model as factors and numerical features on the other hand.

However some of the numerical columns behave more like factors. With this I mean that they show extreme clustering, one can see this by the R-code

```
summary(factor( factor.feature ))
```

giving

```
   0.094      13.207      26.319      39.431      52.544       65.656 
     421      399522      181252       47368       11290         2302 

  78.768      91.881     104.993     118.105     131.218      157.443 
     416         112          16           6           3            1
```

where the top number in each pair is the value and the lower number is the number
of times it occurred.

Or more accurately, this is the output:

[image]

Is there a statistical concept that helps me to decide whether a numerical value is discrete?

Comment: What do you know about the DGM (data generating mechanism) for these features? For instance, are these values imputed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell it's discrete because the same values occur many times (they can also be described as "heavily tied"; continuous values would occur once only (though in practice data are often rounded to only a few figures and then there could be some repetition)

So basically, if there's a lot of repetition, as there is here, then it's discrete.

However, in this case you don't just have discrete values, they're actually on a lattice (which with univariate data means there's a constant-size minimum gap between values):

```
> .09483396 + (13.20718338-.09483396) * (0:12)
 [1]   0.09483396  13.20718338  26.31953280  39.43188222  52.54423164
 [6]  65.65658106  78.76893048  91.88127990 104.99362932 118.10597874
[11] 131.21832816 144.33067758 157.44302700
```

Note that apart from the second-last number in that sequence, all those values occur in your data.

(The gap between values is 13.11235; it's not clear to me how that might arise.)

If you had regular gaps such as these, you wouldn't need repetitions to know it's discrete; even if only one value was present at each of those values in your data, it would mean that it was on a lattice (and hence discrete).

These would be the main ways (seeing repetition and seeing a regular lattice) of identifying discreteness.

However, if there are enough different values possible under a discrete distribution you may not see any repetition and you may not even be able to "spot the gap" in a lattice.

Indeed, you can have discreteness not on a regular lattice and still have no repetitions in a small sample, like this (sorted) sample of size 20 from a discrete distribution which is not on a lattice:

```
  4.833200  5.759216  6.901740  7.432655  7.761573  7.841130  8.149825
  8.587643  8.658004  9.516575  9.578833  9.883175  9.942725 10.060579
 10.118900 10.681726 11.003408 11.055967 11.263369 11.416070
```

(The values are the square roots of a sample from a discrete uniform, shifted up by a constant. With a big clue like that you might be able to figure out what the shift was and then be able to actually show it's discrete but otherwise you might have had trouble working it out from the values alone.)

So it is definitely possible for a distribution to be discrete but effectively indistinguishable from continuous without a very large sample.

On the other hand, as mentioned before values notionally drawn from a continuous distribution may see some repetition because of rounding/recording to only a finite number of figures  -- such as weight, say; even recorded to the nearest gram, you will see repetition in a large sample of weights. The recorded values are effectively discrete, but you would probably want to treat them as continuous.

Ultimately of course, all values are recorded to some finite level of precision, so if you look on a fine enough grain the distinction disappears. However, the distinction remains useful from a modelling point of view and will often relate to your understanding of the variables. Fortunately, the cases where it remains difficult to tell them apart from the numbers alone, even in largish samples, it generally doesn't really matter if you treat them as continuous or discrete; indeed the harder they are to tell apart, the less it matters.

Comment: The lattice is a very good point!

Comment: It is of course valuable to see the lattice structure, but generally speaking wouldn't I encode this just as an ordered factor? But thinking one more time the lattice rather speaks for treating it as numeric ... what do you think?

Comment: and if we decided about them to be discrete: would we treat them as (ordered) factors in statistics software?

Comment: Unless their values represented categories, generally not. If the values have meaning in themselves, then you are nearly always better off not turning them into categorical variables.